# Selecting current html div and appending to list n amount of times using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a script that allows a user to add user input into a sample analysis and to add additional samples with a button `id="addsmplbtn"`. However it has come to my attention that in some cases a user would want to fill in one sample and then multiply it for various samples that require the same analyses an n amount of times.

The script below is a very simple version of the actual script. Adding various samples one-by-one is achieved, however I am struggling with adding multiple samples at the same time:

```js
var variable = 1;

    $("#addsmplbtn").click(function() {
        var element = $(".samplesinfo.hidden").clone(true);
        element.removeClass("hidden").appendTo(".paste:last");
        $(".panel").hide();

    });

$(document).ready(function() {          

        $("#samplebtn").click(function(){
            $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle();
        });

        $("#addsmplbtn").trigger("click");
    });
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addsmplbtn">Add Sample</button>

    <div id="samplesinfo" class="samplesinfo hidden">
        <button type="button" id="samplebtn" class="samplebtn"></i>Sample</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <input type="text" name="input1">Input1
            <input type="text" name="input2">Input2
            <select>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option>Option1</option>
                <option>Option2</option>
            </select>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">Check1
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">Check2
            <input type="text" name="batch_count" id="batch_count" placeholder="enter batch count">
            <button type="button" id="add_batch" class="add_batch">Add batch samples</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <form>
        <div>
            <h3>No hidden content</h3>


        </div>
        <div id="paste" class="paste">          
        </div>
    </form>
```

The following section is the jQuery I am struggling with, to select a single sample, fill in `<input>` and then to append that element an n amount of times:

```
$("#add_batch").on("click", function() {

        var times = $(this).current("#batch_count").val();

        for(var i=0; i < times; i++) {
            $(this).current("#add_batch").click(function() {
                var element = $(this).current(".samplesinfo").clone(true);
                element.appendTo(".paste:last");
                $(".panel").hide();
            });
        }
    });
```

Can anybody please help me adjust the code so that it could achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addSample(source, target, howMany) {
  for(var i=0; i < howMany; i++) {
    console.log("adding "+$(source).attr("id")+" to "+target);
    var element = $(source).clone(true);
    element.removeClass("hidden").appendTo(target);
    $(".panel").hide();
  }
}

function getInputValue(sender, inputName) {
  return $(sender).parent().children('input[name="'+inputName+'"]').val();
}

$("#addsmplbtn").click(function() {
    addSample($("#samplesinfo"), $(".paste:last"), 1);
});

$(document).ready(function() {          
        $("#samplebtn").click(function(){
            $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle();
        });
        addSample($("#samplesinfo"), $(".paste:last"), 1);
    });


$("#add_batch").on("click", function() {
        var times = getInputValue(this, "batch_count");

        addSample($(this).parent().parent().get(0), $(".paste:last"), times);
    });
```

Please don't use the same id attribute on multiple elements. This causes many problems.

Comment: This works nicely thank you. Please, would you be able to edit your post so that there are comments on what exactly each part of the code does since it is a different approach than mine?

Comment: Okay but please remember that this code uses anti-pattern (creating multiple elements with same id). I will elaborate on this by tommorrow 'cause I'm on the phone now and it is pain to write.

Comment: First thing to point out is code duplication. You had two occurrences of code for cloning the div: one in addsmplbtn click event and one in add_batch click event. Basically, having duplicated code is strong indicator that things can be done better. That's why I created add_sample function. getInputValue is just shorthand for what it contains. It get the values of inputs contained in the same container as sender (it is called by add_batch, so it can access values of any input in parent div). As it is called only once, for access requested number of copies, it is not really necessary.

Comment: addsamplbtn click event now calls aforementioned addSample function. You need to make one copy, so third parameter is one. Please note that now we have single point of failure. On document.ready we are not triggering click on button, but we call our function. I thing this approach is elegant, but that's just my opinion. add_batch click event handler is a little bit tricky, as we need to copy two level up (parent of this button is .panel, but we need to copy #samplesinfo (which is parent of .panel). That's why we used parent().parent(). Perhaps this can be done in more elegant way.

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you perhaps tell me why a selected dropdown list does not repeat with batching?

Comment: Because of jquery clone() method, take a look at the docs: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

"Note: For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements. When cloning input elements, the dynamic state of the element (e.g., user data typed into text inputs and user selections made to a checkbox) is retained in the cloned elements."

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle can be a possible solution.

**Never use multiple id-s on HTML elements, this is what classes for!**

**Use:**
`$(document).on('{event}', '{selector}', function(){})`
**on dynamically added elements.**

```js
// Add sample click event listener
$(document).on('click', '#add-sample', function() {
  var element = $(".samples-info.hidden").clone(true);
  element.removeClass("hidden").appendTo(".paste:last");
  $(".panel").hide();
});

// Add batch click event listener
$(document).on('click', ".add_batch", function() {
  var times = $(this).siblings('.batch_count').val();
  var element = $(".samples-info.hidden").clone(true);
  for(var i=0; i < times; i++) {
    $(".paste:last").append("<div class='.samples-info'>" + element.html() + "</div>");
  }
  $(".panel").hide();
});

// Toggling the sample's panel
$(document).on('click', '.sample-btn', function() {
     $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle();
  });

$(document).ready(function() {          
// Triggering the first sample on ready
  $("#add-sample").trigger("click");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-sample">Add Sample</button>
    <div class="samples-info hidden">
        <button type="button" id="sample-btn" class="sample-btn">
          Sample
        </button>
        <div class="panel">
            <input type="text" name="input1">Input1
            <input type="text" name="input2">Input2
            <select>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option>Option1</option>
                <option>Option2</option>
            </select>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">Check1
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">Check2
            <input type="text" class="batch_count" placeholder="enter batch count">
            <button type="button" class="add_batch" class="add_batch">
              Add batch samples
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form>
        <div>
            <h3>No hidden content</h3>


        </div>
        <div id="paste" class="paste">          
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: This works fine for adding the number of required samples, however it also needs to keep the input that was inserted by the user. For example it I add "test" into input1 and append it 3 times, the other sample elements should also have "test" in the appended elements. Could you perhaps help with this as well?